# What's the relation between classic asp and a IIS application pool?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, application-pool

- Does asp run in the IIS application pool for which the website is configured? Or is the application pool only for asp.NET applications.
- How do those two relate to each other, what do i need to know to understand who's doing what and where are they doing it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ASP Classic application will run in the application pool to which it is assigned.

ASP.NET application also run in their assigned application, hence its possible that one or more ASP.NET applications and one or more ASP applications will run in the same pool and therefore share process(es).

In IIS6 there is little relationship between the two (ASP and ASP.NET applications) they simply do their thing side-by-side.  They share the same virtual memory space so if one is a hog the other is affected.  Additionally if one crashes the process all other apps that are in the pool (ASP and/or ASP.NET) are affected.  They also share a common ISAPI filter stack which runs on a per-process basis.

In IIS7 with the integrated pipeline things become, well, more integrated.  ASP classic relies on the .NET based pipeline to deliver requests to handle.