# How to check for unclosed connections on Windows Server 2003 IIS/ASP Classic?

Tags: asp-classic

I inherited some bad code that doesn't close connections -  it's Classic ASP written on windows server 2k3 64-bit (run in 32-bit mode).

Where can I look to see what connections are lingering for an app or app pool?

Comment: Not sure if it really matters. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608165/what-happens-when-not-closing-recordsets-in-classic-asp

Comment: Connections to what?  A DB Connection?  How have you confirmed that there are lingering connections?

Comment: I've been seeing a lot of code where the connections aren't set to nothing or recordsets aren't closed. I reasonably suspect there are more and I want to see where they're happening.