# Memory monitoring/leaks/issues in classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, iis, memory-leaks, asp-classic, windows-server-2012

I've been asked to look at a server that has slowed to stopping point.  The server has hundreds of classic ASP sites running on it, and upon examining some code, I see there are a lot of instances where ADODB.Recordset (plus other) objects are being opened, used, but never destroyed (set to Nothing).  I appreciate that there may be other issues too that I haven't spotted yet...

The original code developers are refusing to take any responsibility, as they state that following initial deployment of the sites, they worked fine for years.

There isn't enough hours in the day unfortunately to examine all the code across all sites.  Therefore, is there any application available that can monitor memory usage, leaks, or anything that might help diagnose what's causing this stoppage of the server?

Originally the sites were on Win2003, IIS6, but have now been moved over to Win2012, IIS8.  The slowdown is now being experienced on the new server as well, so I'm sure its not a hardware fault.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Please note I tagged this with ASP.NET too as I appreciate most classic ASP dev's are now using .NET, but might be able to suggest something from their experience...

Comment: It is possible to configure the application pools to restart as soon as a certain memory threshold is hit. This will at least keep things a bit snappyy, but it will reset your sites every now and then. For debugging, look into IIS debug diagnostics http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919790

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for all the open connections to cause a problem under high load, but even back in ASP Classic there was some decent garbage collection. Objects and connections left open were automatically closed when the page was done processing. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1613337/25163

I've used a crude [ASP Profiler](http://aspprofiler.sourceforge.net/) in the past to look for where the specific bottlenecks are in the ASP/VBScript sites I still maintain. I'd look at the logs for any specific pages with problematic load times and target those first.

If you don't already have a program for that, I've used the free version of [SmarterStats](http://www.smartertools.com/smarterstats/web-analytics-seo-software.aspx) on a couple of projects. The server that runs SmarterStats would need to be able to run an ASP.NET site though.

Without a little more investigation into the most problematic areas, any other advice would be a shot in the dark. Especially since the real problem could just as likely be on the database end of the equation. Profiling problematic pages would help find that out.

Comment: Very helpful answer, thanks.  Again I feel myself at the moment like its a shot in the dark.  I have a strong programming background and can see a boat-load of issues with the code.  It's just a case of trying to isolate the worst-performing app's first...!

Answer (score 0):

Other than going into the each file and manually setting each Recodset, Connection, Command etc object to nothing, I don't think there is much else you can do.

I had something similar years ago and my only solution was the above.

Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Destroying recordsets (set to nothing) from my experience does not affect performance. You need to check for things like:

- Database connections being open then not being closed.
- Use of application variables (these chew a ton of memory).
- Excessive use of session variables (to an extent).
- Pulling unneeded data or not paging correcting with SQL queries.
- Excessive file operations.